# How to scale and manage IAM roles and policies in CDK without running into size limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

### Issue

So in our CDK code we basically create roles and then assign them policies via `.grant()` or `.grant<something>()` function of the respective component (e.g. an SQS Queue):

```js
import iam from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam";
import sqs from "@aws-cdk/aws-sqs";

declare const fooRole: iam.Role;
declare const barQueue: sqs.Queue;
declare const bazDlq: sqs.Queue;

barQueue.grantSendMessages(role);
bazDlq.grant(role, "sqs:ListDeadLetterSourceQueues");
```

For an admin-like role this can pretty fast be a problem since admin-like roles get a lot of grants from various components, which lead to a policy size limit error on AWS side:

> Maximum policy size of 10240 bytes exceeded for role my-admin-role-SOMEHASH (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code: LimitExceeded; Request ID: 6206d0f5-e107-4c4a-a452-0e1cbc7868d6; Proxy: null)

Luckily there is a feature flag to enable minification of policies:

```json
{
  "app": "...",
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies": true
}
```

This helped me to reduce the size of policy JSONs, but we plan to add much more resources (for example SQS queues) which the admin role needs access to.

### Question

What would be the best way to manage IAM roles and policies so they are able to scale with the actual application?

Comment: most people use a lot of wildcard actions for admin-type roles, like `List*`, `Get*`, `Describe*` for every service.

Comment: @MattTimmermans valid point but sometimes you don't want them to be able to do everything .. you could for example have support admins that probably have a lot of rights but you shouldn't give them more rights than they need. But wildcard actions might be a good idea for read-only actions since they tend to be not that risky.